# How can I make such bitwise operations faster?

Tags: c, optimization, bitwise-operators

The code is very simple.

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
{    
    int r = (1 << a) | (1 << b) | (1 << c) | (1 << d) | (1 << e ) | (1 << f) | (1 << g);
    return r;
}
```

Assume all the arguments are no greater than 30.

It seems to be a very primitive function, but after compiling with the "-Ofast" flag, it still takes 28 instructions to compute r.

Is there an alternative code that can make these bitwise operations faster?

Comment: have you tried it with "unsigned char" data types, or is the compiler already optimizing the type?

Comment: If you are trying to optimize the assembly code, why not write it yourself?

Comment: @Miguel how would `unsigned char` help when there may be 30 bit shifts?

Comment: You're it wont. I was just thinking about the memory foot print optimization not the speed optimization.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that the code is not optimal?

Comment: Are you calling the function with actual variables or only with integer literals / `#define`s ? If the latter, inlining the function might result in having the compiler precomputing all the bit-wise operations.

Comment: If you're compiling to x86/x64, the only register you can use for variable shift is `cl`.  You might be getting a lot of extra `mov cl, bla` in there.  No way out of that though.

Comment: Intel has BTS instruction, resembling `a|=1<<(b&31)` while modifying CF. So adding the modulus might result in 8 instruction sequence.

Comment: No, I am not trying to optimize the assembly code. I want a portable C code that can run much faster. The time and space exchange is a good approach. However, I am expecting something smarter, for example some crazy math that can compute these with around 10 bitwise operations.

Comment: @akisuihkonen great point, but I don't usually see compilers using the really sweet instructions like that.  Intel isa was originally designed for assembly programmers, not compilers.

Comment: The number of instructions doesn't make code fast or slow; using bts was about 3 times as slow as compiler-optimized (not bothering to count only for the kernel). My previous point was that with adding code the compiler would be allowed to map the more complex sequence to the equivalent instruction.

Answer (score 5):

28 instructions is rather fast.
Consider what you're doing here. You have:

- 7 shift operations
- 6 OR operations
- 1 memory assignment operation

That already requires at least 14 instructions. Now there are additional instructions that are necessary such as storing the intermediate results and loading operands into registers.

If you want deeper analysis, post the assembly output.

**Edit**: Now to the possible optimization of your algorithm.

You *might* be able to gain a bit more speed by sacrificing some memory. Precompute the values for each possible bit being set in 32-bit value, e.g. something like that: `int bit2value[32]={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,...};` In your function instead of performing the shift operations you can replace them with looking up into the precomputed map: `int r = bit2value[a] | bit2value[b] | bit2value[c]...;` This can theoretically save the need for some intermediate storing operations.

Comment: It's not a lot of memory (upper limit int [30]), and you get rid of the need to load the value of the shifted bits to a register.  `mov edx, [arg]; or eax, [precalcArray+edx*4]` is all that's needed per argument.  So you do cut it in half here.  However, don't confuse number of instructions with speed.  Memory access is rather costly compared to integer math.

Comment: @sqykly Yes, it's not a lot of memory, but in this case this microoptimization is probably an overengineering. It won't cut the number of instructions in half. Loading shifted bits to a register doesn't constitute half of the instructions.

Comment: 28 instructions is just 4 per argument, which my answer identifies.  2 is half of 4, I believe.

Comment: Thank you guys. I came up with the same after I posted this. I did a test just now, appears that this does save a half of instructions.

Comment: @henrylee have you profiled it though?  I'm interested to hear what happened when you halved the instructions but doubled the memory fetches and probably introduced a lot of pipeline stalls.  If you just need small code, though, great.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Visual Studio 2015* (32bit, optimized for space), the following code results in `21` rather than `24` instructions:

```
typedef struct container
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
} CONTAINER;

int foo2(CONTAINER *ct)
{
    int r = (1 << ct->a) | (1 << ct->b) | (1 << ct->c) | (1 << ct->d) | (1 << ct->e) | (1 << ct->f) | (1 << ct->g);
    return r;
}
```

The assembly code (21 rather than 20 instructions, sorry!):

```
1   push    esi
2   mov edx, ecx
3   xor esi, esi
4   inc esi
5   mov ecx, DWORD PTR [edx+24]
6   mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+20]
7   shl esi, cl
8   mov ecx, DWORD PTR [edx+8]
9   bts esi, eax
10  mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+16]
11  bts esi, eax
12  mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+12]
13  bts esi, eax
14  bts esi, ecx
15  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [edx+4]
16  bts esi, ecx
17  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [edx]
18  bts esi, ecx
19  mov eax, esi
20  pop esi
21  ret 0
```

Comment: I am a little puzzled.  Please post 20 assembly instructions that accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

For each argument you need:

```
mov cl, argument
mov edx, 1
shl edx, cl
or eax, edx
```

I believe your function had 7 arguments?  Up to `g`?  27 (4*7 - 1) is as low as it goes, since you can calculate the result of the shift directly in `eax` for the first argument.  You can't *not* load each argument into a register, as the instruction doesn't operate on memory directly.  You can't shift 1 without setting something to 1 every time.  Obviously you can't do without the shift instructions or the `or`.

Comment: Well you don't need the first `or`, so that's only 27 instructions, but your point still stands

Comment: You need to replace it with a zeroing `xor eax, eax`

Comment: You can just put the first one in `eax` though, `mov eax, 1 \ etc`